# Error in compiling linphone in android

Tags: android, linphone

I am trying to build linphone for Android in Windows 7.
 I have completed the  steps 0,1 and 2 given in README file.
 I have set all the required paths, and installed cygwin. 
 But , when I run Makefile script, it is throwing error for the line below:
                   all: update-project prepare-sources generate-apk
 error:
                   all : command not found.

Could you please guide me how to run Makefile script.
 Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Makefile` is not a script to run; it is input used by `make` utility